# Strongly continuous and strong topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $H$ be a Hilbert spave and $B(H)$ the set of bounded linear maps $H\to H$. Here bounded means in terms of the operator norm.

If $X$ is a metric space, there is a notion what it means for a map $X\to B(H)$ to be strongly continuous.

In this context, what is the strong topology on $B(H)$?

Answer (score 0):

$T_n\to T$ strongly if $||T_nx-Tx||\to0$ for every $x$.

Comment: How does this gives a topology on $B(H)$?

Comment: Let $V_{x,r}=\{T:||Tx||<r\}$; they should form a subbasis  at the origin.